# How do unchecked exceptions (ex C#) differ from Java-esque exceptions?

Tags: c#, java, exception

I've seen lots of remarks about Java's checked exceptions, with the implication that something else (often C#) is substantially different/superior in this regard.  I'm not interested in the language wars aspect, but I would like to know how languages without checked exceptions differ from Java's model.  Would you get the same result if you changed all Java's exceptions to extend `RuntimeException`?

Java uses checked exceptions for system errors (disk full, network connection errors) and unchecked for programmer errors (invalid array indices, type conversion errors).  Do languages without checked exceptions maintain this distinction another way or just treat them all the same?

---

Since someone voted to close as subjective, I'll emphasize again: I **don't care** which language people think is better.  I'm only asking about the actual operational differences that programmers will have to code around when using the different exception models.  I only have experience the Java version, so I'm trying to find out how the other way works.

Comment: Just a tidbit: Yes, you would get the same result if you changed all Java Exceptions to extend `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is essentially no difference between Exceptions in the two languages.

The only large difference is that in Java some Exceptions (checked) will generate a compile error if they are not explicitly caught or thrown.

C# does not treat any of its exceptions differently.  A `NullReferenceException` is essentially the same as a, `IOException`.

When programming in C# you must have a better knowledge of what errors could happen, and which ones you can handle.  Java makes it easier by reminding you to handle the case where something out of your control went wrong.

Comment: "C# does not treat any of its exceptions." - What does that mean?

Comment: @Greg, I forgot to finish my sentence.  Oops.  Fixed.

Comment: Actually C# treats a few exceptions as special. The primary one is AccessViolationException. catch(Exception e) won't catch a system generated one.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem with checked exceptions is that in some (many?) cases, you write code such that the exception never occurs or you don't care if it does, forcing a user to "catch" non-throwable or non-recoverable exceptions, and suchlike. Then you have to consider the case where a user doesn't care if their app terminates with a checked exception, let's say, a hobbyist or student developer. Now you have to go and mark every function with every checked exception that might ever occur, even the ones that would only occur if you ran on the Martian JVM with a blue moon.

Checked exceptions are like const correctness in C++- they're a great idea, but the language only has the most primitive implementation and the amount of metaphorical red tape surrounding the whole thing is abysmal, to the point where it might be easier to just not have the damn thing.

I don't know of any other language that has checked exceptions.

In C++ no primitive operation throws, and not many of the more advanced operations or library functions throw. There are generally just far less exceptions in C++. I can't really speak for C#. The thing about C++ is that if you get an unhandled exception, your debugger will easily tell you where it came from, making it relatively trivial to hunt them down and removing the need for a bunch of `catch(something) { printfailure("funcname"); abort_program(); }` repetitive catches.

Comment: I find that you have to have an IDE to help you maintain the checked exceptions.  It is unfortunate that you should need to do that, but one you let the IDE work it out, its not a headache as I see it.

Comment: @Peter: I never saw a Java IDE that would manage the checked exceptions for me.

Comment: In IntelliJ CE, (free version) if you throw a checked exception it gives you two auto-fixes. "Add Exception(s) to Method Signature" and "Surround with try/catch" if you add to the method signature it organises the exceptions to simplify them and offers to add them to any parent interface/overriden method as required.  You can throw a checked exception in a nested method without changing any code manually.  Conversely it offers to remove checked exceptions in "throws" which are not thrown or reduce them e.g. from IOException, to a more specific exception.

Comment: If you need to throw a checked exception, but the parent won't allow it, you can either wrap it (which I don't like as it changes the exception) or use Thread.stop(checkedException) which allows you to throw a checked exception as it it were an unchecked one.

Answer (score 0):

You will find, as I found, that Java's checked exceptions are broken the first time you need to write a higher-level (reusable) algorithm.